# Ruby Gem for intra-site messaging? (think LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Many sites have communication via the site (instead of via email).  Examples:

- LinkedIn: Click "Inbox" at the top of the screen.
- Facebook: Click "Messages" in the left sidebar.

Is there a gem that provides this sort of functionality?  Googling hasn't turned up much, because the search terms are so generic - "Rails gem messaging" "Ruby gem email" etc. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [an old plugin](http://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages), [another old plugin](http://github.com/tongueroo/acts_as_mailable) and [a relatively fresh one](http://github.com/pluginaweek/has_messages).